# Tomcat Weld error - WELD-000341 - Unable to load current conversations from the associated request

Tags: java, tomcat, cdi, weld

I am using Tomcat 7 + weld-servlet-2.2.3 and weld errors are occuring too frequently.

Errors like: WELD-000335: Context is already active and WELD-000341 - Unable to load current conversations from the associated request are occuring intermittently.

I am using three filters: org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationFilter and org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.

Please let me know how to resolve these errors with Tomcat.

Comment: We are seeing "javax.servlet.ServletException: WELD-000341: Unable to load current conversations from the associated request, something went badly wrong when associate() was called" also. This is on GlassFish 4.1. We're tracking the bug here: https://github.com/IQSS/dataverse/issues/1516